# Why Spring Cloud Dataflow Supplier properties does not appear?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I have configuration properties for de Supplier:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties("sybase.supplier")
public class SybaseSupplierProperties {
    private short canal = 0;
    private int pollSize = 10;
}
```

I am injecting it on the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SybaseSupplierProperties.class)
public class SybaseSupplier {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final SybaseSupplierProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public SybaseSupplier(DataSource dataSource,
                          SybaseSupplierProperties properties) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

I have the maven dependency to generate it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

It is generated as spring-configuration-metadata.json

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "sybase.supplier",
      "type": "br.com.clamed.daflow.apps.sybasesupplier.SybaseSupplierProperties",
      "sourceType": "br.com.clamed.daflow.apps.sybasesupplier.SybaseSupplierProperties"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "sybase.supplier.canal",
      "type": "java.lang.Short",
      "sourceType": "br.com.clamed.daflow.apps.sybasesupplier.SybaseSupplierProperties",
      "defaultValue": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "sybase.supplier.poll-size",
      "type": "java.lang.Integer",
      "sourceType": "br.com.clamed.daflow.apps.sybasesupplier.SybaseSupplierProperties",
      "defaultValue": 10
    }
  ],
  "hints": []
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.intControleSupplier-out-0=output
spring.cloud.function.definition=intControleSupplier
```

Internal maven repo is registed.

The app is imported:

```
app register --name jdbc-sybase-supplier --type source --uri maven://br.com.clamed.cloud.dataflow.apps:jdbc-sybase-supplier:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

When I use it, properties do not show:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all the properties from `spring-configuration-metadata.json` would be available when the SCDF server retrieves the application properties. This is to `limit` the number of properties get loaded at the UI. But this doesn't mean you can't set those properties as application properties. It is just that those properties would be available in the SCDF web UI as well as shell completion as the application properties for you to choose.

In your case, to make your `SybaseSupplierProperties`  available, you need to add a dataflow configuration file that specifies what properties should be available for SCDF to retrieve when loading the app.

You either need to specify `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` (deprecated in the recent releases) or `dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` inside `classpath*:/META-INF/` with the properties classes name you want to include as application configuration properties.

For instance, in your case you would need to the following content in `/META-INF/dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` :

```
configuration-properties.classes=br.com.clamed.daflow.apps.sybasesupplier.SybaseSupplierProperties
```

You can also checkout the documentation on this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting)

Comment: Did that but no success. I suspect the app registering is pointing to the wrong place, because even if I type the maven URL wrong it successfully register the app.

Comment: managed to get it working, it was blocked on the company firewall. SCDF was no able to access the maven repo.

Comment: "here" link is broken. here is a link to the site - https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/applications/application-metadata/#exposing-application-properties-for-data-flow and to the reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-application-properties